# Why doesn't my .htaccess file redirect to https? How to fix?

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https, cloudflare

Oh Jesus, I've tried this a million times, a million different ways using Stackoverflow, using blogs, my web host even did it at one point, to no success, or maybe my fiddling with caching broke it.

I want to redirect all HTTP:// traffic to https, it's detering folk from buying.

So this is the content of the file, what needs to change???

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
AddHandler server-parsed .html .htm
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE .shtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.pottertour.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 0 day"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 month"  
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES
```

OK I tried removing the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrappers as per MrWhite's comment, and it seemed to put the loading in a constant loop.  So I returned it to what it was previously, but without the wrappers. As per below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pottertour.co.uk [NC]   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.pottertour.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

- It's now blocking the loading of my google fonts and styles.css.
  Really CRITICAL!
- It also fails to redirect.

Solutions and explanations well appreciated.

OK well thanks to MrWhite I've had another go, the whole .htacess file now stands at this:

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
AddHandler server-parsed .html .htm
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE .shtml
</IfModule> 

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 day"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 month"  
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Note I've removed all references to a permanent redirect by omitting the R=301

I've set a canonical https:// URL on all pages anyway, so I think adding to .htaccess doesn't help much.

It's still not accessing my styles.css or downloading google fonts. Nor is the browser executing on page javascript accordions correctly (how bizarre it's embedded on the page!)

I've contacted 1&1 my web host and asked them to ensure the .htacess file is 'refreshed'...  I'll go off and research Cloudfare.

Comment: "my web host even did it at one point" - Your "web host" really should know a way that works since this can be host dependent (if they have front-end caching proxies etc.). The directives you have above is one perfectly valid way to do this, so what happens? Nothing? An error? Redirect-loop? You should remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper.

Comment: Is `potertour.co.uk` your actual domain? This isn't even answering to DNS requests for me (ie. it doesn't resolve)?!

Comment: Yes you're quite right, it's the wrong URL, should be 
www.pottertour.co.uk 
Instead of pasting from the .htacess I was pasting from the blog tutorial I pasted to .htacess.  I wanted to finally fix this after many attempts, instead I derailed my whole website by somehow blocking styles.css!  Jesus!  I've tried removing the wrapper as you suggested but it put it in a constant loop. So in a panic I changed it back to what it was previously, minus the wrapper, it continues to fail to redirect to https but now it also BLOCKS styles.css and my google fonts - NIGHTMARE!

Comment: I doubt very much that "Jesus" has got any hands in this. In general: religious delusion really has no place in informatics ...

Comment: Maybe, however, I do need my ```styles.css``` to come back from the dead, so there's a thing or two to learn there. Can you be my Saviour @askascha?  No crosses - promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having had a quick look at your site, it would seem you are using Cloudflare (which acts a proxy in front of your application server<sup>***1**</sup>), in which case you would need to do something like the following instead to redirect HTTP to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You do not need the `<IfModule>` wrapper.

You should first test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have confirmed it works as intended. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.

You *need* to clear your browser cache before testing.

This does not canonicalise the www/non-www subdomain.

<sup>***1**</sup> Cloudflare acts as a front-end SSL proxy in front of your application server. This means that the connection from the client to the proxy is *secure* (ie. over HTTPS, when redirected), but the connection from the proxy to your application server is always HTTP. Which is why you can't detect the HTTPS connection on the application server itself and you end up getting a redirect loop. `X-Forwarded-Proto` is a header set/forwarded by the proxy to inform the backend/application server of the protocol used by the client.

---

**UPDATE:** I've noticed that while the above redirect now works, you are only sending www subdomain requests through Cloudflare. Requests for the domain apex (ie. `example.com`) are going directly to your origin server (Apache) and are consequently not being redirected by the above rule.

*Everything* (or *nothing*) should be sent through Cloudflare, so this is really a DNS config issue. However, we can resolve this by implementing a non-www to www redirect in `.htaccess` *before* the above HTTP to HTTPS redirect. (I'm assuming www is the preferred canonical URL?)

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-www to www (and HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (Cloudflare)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note that the earlier rule (HTTP to HTTPS) is now second.

This does assume you have no other subdomains. ie. `example.com` and `www.example.com` only. If you have other subdomains then you may decide you want to hardcode the domain in the first rule (similar to what you did earlier), for example:

```
# Redirect non-www to www (and HTTPS) - domain hardcoded
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me MrWhite, I've done this, albeit switching ```[R=301, L] for [R,L]```, I cleared my browser cache {'cookies & other site data' & 'Cached images & files'}, no change.  I tried Chrome's incognito mode - does this really force reload everything? Still no style.css loading. Also If I paste http://pottertour.co.uk, it does not redirect.  Bit of a meltdown really, I'll be losing bookings.

Comment: Completely bizarre, the non-redirect HTTP version displays styles and fonts and works fully, the HTTPS version doesn't.  Woah!  We have an anomaly Captain.

Comment: Well magically it now seems to work, fully redirecting, thankyou MrWhite you are a CHAMP!  ️  I've fixed the style.css not loading problem by changing from a relative path to their URL online; saddens me though because makes updates a little harder offline.  Extra steps... sigh 

Comment: "I tried Chrome's incognito mode - does this really force reload everything?" - Only if it's a _new_ incognito session. If you already have an incognito window open then it does not. The redirect itself should not have affected the styles loading. When I looked at your site the styles were loading fine, but I only looked at the homepage. "changing from a relative path" - Using relative paths to static resources can certainly cause problems, particularly if you are rewriting the URL (although no evidence of that in your `.htaccess` file). Use root-relative URLs that start with a slash instead.

Comment: @Sam "makes updates a little harder offline" - You should still be developing "locally" using a webserver (Apache) so you can keep the URL-paths the same as the live site. (A little trickier if you are using absolute URLs.) "Note I've removed all references to a permanent redirect by omitting the R=301" - to clarify, the 302/temporary redirect is only for testing purposes. This should ultimately be a 301 permanent redirect.

Comment: @Sam HOWEVER, you do still have a configuration error. Only the www subdomain is being routed through Cloudflare, so only the www subdomain is redirected from HTTP to HTTPS. The domain apex (ie. `example.com`) is going directly to your origin server (bypassing Cloudflare) and being served from Apache. This means that a request for `http://example.com/` (ie. HTTP + non-www) is NOT currently being redirected to HTTPS. This should really be fixed in your DNS to send _all_ requests through Cloudflare, not just the www subdomain. However, we can implement a fix in `.htaccess`. I'll update my answer